# Etherbase/Coinbase account of private net is changed automatically

Tags: coinbase

I am testing on a privatenet, and as I started the chain I have set the etherbase using miner.setEtherbase. However after few hours I see that my etherbase is changed automatically.

> eth.coinbase
>   "0xd9ee4d08a86b430544254ff95e32aa6fcc1d3163"
>
> eth.accounts
>   ["0xc53f820bf0b95d0da114d0ca657dfa00fdf731df"]

I don't have any peers and do not have the culprit account even in my keystore.
Could someone help me on this. This happend in out test region and I need to make sure it will not happen in production.

Comment: Perhaps you left the rpc port accessible and someone used that to change it.